# No name 'DjangoWhiteNoise' in module 'whitenoise.django' Error

Tags: python, django

I'm currently in the process of deploying my django app to Heroku, and the walkthrough I'm following is having me add the following code to my wsgi file. Only issue is that I'm getting an error that `No name 'DjangoWhiteNoise' in module 'whitenoise.django'`

I have whitenoise 5.1.0 installed, but can't figure out how to install whitenoise.django or what the issue is. Any ideas?

wsgi.py

```
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

Comment: The correct import is `from whitenoise.base import WhiteNoise`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is legacy/old way of dealing with whitenoise you should configure it properly [configuration](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets#whitenoise)

> settings.py
>
> ```
> MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
>     # Simplified static file serving.
>     # https://warehouse.python.org/project/whitenoise/
>     'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
>     ...
>
>
>
> STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
> ```

Comment: Adding the STATICFILES_STORAGE  is not really necessary. I suspect there's a missing comma at the end of that middleware you add to settings.py.

Alternatively, check settings.py thoroughly.